# hackerrank nested if-else question explanation

Tags: java

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        String ans;
        if (n % 2 == 1)
            ans = "Weird";
        else {
            if (n >= 2 && n <= 5)
                ans = "Not Weird";
            else if (n >= 5 && n <= 20)
                ans = "Weird";
            else
                ans = "Not Weird";
        }
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
```

- If n  is odd, print Weird
- if n is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to 20, print Weird.
- If n is even and greater than  20 , print Not Weird
- If  is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5 , print Not Weird

The above code works fine but my question is   if I enter *3*  as input  3%2=1 which  should  print weird which it does exactly does, then how did it pass  the test case when it is clearly stated that *If  is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5 , print Not Weird*

[image file of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnbFv.png)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212515/discussion-on-question-by-satoshi-hackerrank-nested-if-else-question-explanation).

Answer (score 0):

From the question link

Sample Case 0: 
`n` is odd and odd numbers are weird, so we print `Weird`.

Explanation:-

```
if (n % 2 == 1) // This will check 3%2==1 i.e. true and if block will be executed ans=Weird
    ans = "Weird";
```

As `if` condition is `true`,  `else` block will not be executed and this is the requirement of the question.

***How Does Modulus Divison Work***

The result of a `modulo division(%)` is the `remainder` of an `integer division` of the given numbers.
For example:-

```
3 / 2 = 1, remainder= 1
=> 3 % 2 = 1
```

More Example:-

```
100/10=10, remainder= 0

=> 100%10=0

23/7=3, remainder= 2

=> 23%7=2
```

Hope this Help.

Answer (score 0):

One weird trick to fix your understanding of your code.

```
if (n % 2 == 1)
    ans = "Weird";
```

Let's change it. Also, let's use braces. Even when we don't need to. That's not a weird trick. Pay particular attention to this next bit. We're going to make it work exactly the same way but with no `else` (that's the weird trick).

```
int n = sc.nextInt();
if (n % 2 == 1) {
    System.out.println("Weird");
    System.exit(0); // <-- program ends.
}
if (n >= 2 && n <= 5) {
    System.out.println("Not Weird");
    System.exit(0); // <-- program ends.
}
if (n >= 5 && n <= 20) {
    System.out.println("Weird");
    System.exit(0); // <-- program ends.
}
System.out.println("Not Weird");
```

Comment: I was not asking the solution ,I just wanted to ask how the  above code is working, I had solved that  question in my own way but wanted to understand how the above code was working

Comment: @satoshi **Exactly** like this. Same logic. 100%. I did not solve the question. And I only used the code in your question. I **may** have used some stuff I learned in college about compilers (but don't worry about that right now).

Comment: @ElliottFrissch thank you  for your effort,I will have to work harder on this  I guess

Comment: @satoshi Which part do you not understand? Are you still stuck on three? Look at my answer. When `n` is `3` what happens? It prints weird and then ends. Looks at your code. What happens when `n` is three? It enters the very first `if`. It then prints weird and ends. It does not enter the `else` at all when `n` is `3`. The braces are ***optional***. And, perhaps this is the sticking point, `else` is **not** `finally`. Which works like you seem to be convinced `else` works.